# Limiting WordPress search result items

Tags: wordpress

How to limit in WordPress search result page to 5 or 10 items?

Maybe any change in `general-template.php?

Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://wptricks.net/tutorial-to-display-a-different-number-of-post-on-search-result/) article, you can achieve this by using the following code:

```
function change_wp_search_size($queryVars) {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['s']) ) // Make sure it is a search page
        $queryVars['posts_per_page'] = 10; // Change 10 to the number of posts you would like to show
    return $queryVars; // Return our modified query variables
}
add_filter('request', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

Answer (score 6):

### Changing The Number Of Results Per Page

By default WordPress uses the number defined under ***Settings > Reading*** (blog pages show at most…) to define how many results appear on the search results page. If you would like to show more, less or infinite results on your search page you can do so using the following code:

```
// Alter search posts per page
function pd_search_posts_per_page($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','pd_search_posts_per_page' );
```

Answer (score 1):

For WP_Query() you can set it using posts_per_page="your value".

Also, have a look at this : https://digwp.com/2009/12/limit-posts-without-plugin/